# i need drag n drop in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, drag-and-drop

I'v bean searching for a such plugin and I think found it 
http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/posts/2008-05-18-1/jquery-drag-and-drop-and-resize-event-delegation.html

but the problem is .. how can I define events? .. when the object gets dropped or re-sized I call a function that print all changes in some  like

```
name:div1;
top:10;
left:12;  
width:100;
height:19;
```

.. Is that possible fir this plug-in or any other?

if there is any plug-in that does it all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at JQuery UI?  They have draggable and droppable classes that seem to be exactly what you're looking for.  I'm including a link to the demo page, if it doesn't seem like what you're after, could yuou please explain the situation a little better?

[Demo Site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)